# Optimizing video loading on web page

Tags: jquery, html5-video, lazy-loading, single-page-application, fullpage.js

I have a single page application which contains multiple video tags in each section. Height of the window is height of the section. Each tag has a different videos with the format of MP4. I want to load these videos quickly without impacting the page load time so I have tried it to load by lazy load using jquery. But the problem is size of the video file is 5MB and it takes time to load. Is any other possible way to load my first section video on page load and rest after page load completes or as background process without showing to user.

I'm using fullpage js for my single page application. It has a future for lazy loading and I'm using that for loading my video content. Like I said earlier each video is 5Mb of file size. Here is the code which used in my single page application.

```
<video>
  <source data-src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have done so far, add some code and the results. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @lordrhodos. Please find the attached sample code in my question.

Answer (score 7):

I do such tasks with lazy loading of this elements, each by each. For this you could use [`jQuery.Lazy`](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy) and the [`AV` plugin](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins#audio--video-loader), to handle such tags. This is pretty easy to implement.

Instead of your original `video` tag:

```
<video>
  <source data-src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

You change it to:

```
<video data-src="video.mp4|video/mp4"></video>
```

Or another way to write:

```
<video>
  <data-src src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></data-src>
</video>
```

Then add the two script files to your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.5/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.5/plugins/jquery.lazy.av.min.js"></script>
```

And initialize the plugin afterwards in you page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $("video").lazy();
});
</script>
```

Thats all. The videos will be loaded when the user reaches the viewport. You could go any further, by shoing a loading animation or something else.

Comment: great answer, key item that needs to be added for this to work is the data type in the data src... e.g. data-src="video.mp4|video/mp4" would not work without it!!